# Globally-scoped variable: can its value change before it is picked up by the thread?

Tags: python, multithreading, scope

In the following code, you see that `pickledList` is being used by the thread and is set in the global scope.

If the variable that the thread was using was set dynamically somewhere down below in that final while loop, is it possible that its value could change before the thread got to use it? How can I set a value dynamically in the loop, send it off to the thread and **make sure** that its value doesn't change before the thread gets to use it?

```
import pickle
import Queue
import socket
import threading

someList = [ 1, 2, 7, 9, 0 ]
pickledList = pickle.dumps ( someList )

class ClientThread ( threading.Thread ):
   def run ( self ):
      while True:
         client = clientPool.get()
         if client != None:
            print 'Received connection:', client [ 1 ] [ 0 ]
            client [ 0 ].send ( pickledList )
            for x in xrange ( 10 ):
               print client [ 0 ].recv ( 1024 )
            client [ 0 ].close()
            print 'Closed connection:', client [ 1 ] [ 0 ]


clientPool = Queue.Queue ( 0 )

for x in xrange ( 2 ):
   ClientThread().start()

server = socket.socket ( socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM )
server.bind ( ( '', 2727 ) )
server.listen ( 5 )

while True:
   clientPool.put ( server.accept() )
```

EDIT:

Here is a better example of my problem. If you run this, sometimes the values change before the thread can output them, causing some to be skipped:

```
from threading import Thread
class t ( Thread ):
    def run(self):
        print "(from thread) ",
        print i

for i in range(1, 50):    
    print i
    t().start()
```

How can I pass the value in `i` to the thread in such a way that its no longer bound to the variable, so that if the value stored in `i` changes, the value the thread is working with is not affected.

Comment: They're entirely different questions referencing the same source listing. In the first question I didn't understand the scoping. In this question I don't understand how to protect the data in a variable being passed to the thread.

Comment: "how can I set a value dynamically down there in that loop, send it off to the thread and MAKE SURE that its value doesn't change before the thread gets to use it?"

What does that mean? The value must not change until after the thread has accessed it?

Comment: either that, or I need to send the value to the thread in a way that it ends up in a new scope where changing the original value wont effect the value that the thread is using

Comment: That's not very clear. Why would you want to send a new value to a thread if it's not supposed to use it?

Comment: well the problem is that the value is never sent to the thread in the example i'm looking at. The thread is using a variable from the global scope. My problem is, what if I called a thread with the intention of using the value stored in that variable, but the value changed before the thread got a chance to use it. My question is, how would I go about passing the value in that variable to the thread in a way that changing the value in the initial variable would not effect the value that the thread is working with.

Comment: Okay, I edited the post with a better example, check that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option 1: you can pass arguments into each Thread when it is instantiated:

```
ClientThread(arg1, arg2, kwarg1="three times!").start()
```

in which case your `run` method will be called:

```
run(arg1, arg2, kwarg1="three times!")
```

by the Thread instance when you call `start()`. If you need to pass mutable objects (dicts, lists, instances) to the function, you must be sure to re-assign the global variable, **not** edit it in place.

Option 2: you can set an instance variable on your `ClientThread` objects:

```
myThread.setMyAttribute('new value')
```

With option 2 you need to be wary of race conditions etc. depending on what the method does. Using `Lock`s whenever you're writing or reading data from/to a thread is a good idea.

Option 3: grab the global when `run` is first called and store a copy locally

```
run(self):
    localVar = globalVar # only for immutable types
    localList = globalList[:] # copy of a list
    localDict = globalDict.copy() # Warning! Shallow copy only!
```

Option 1 is the right way to go if the value a thread is given never needs to change during its lifetime, Option 2 if the value does need to change. Option 3 is a hack.

With regard to generally passing variables/values around, you must remember with Python that immutable objects (strings, numbers, tuples) are passed **by value** and mutable objects (dicts, lists, class instances) are passed **by reference**.

Consequently, altering a string, number or tuple will not affect any instances previously passed that variable, however altering a dict, list or instance will do. Re-assigning a variable to a different object will not affect anything previously given the old value.

Globals certainly shouldn't be used for values that may change (if at all). Basically your example is doing it the wrong way.

Comment: Thanks for baring wiht me there :) very helpful answer.

Comment: Okay, your answer makes perfect sense but it brings up another question. I'm using option 1, but I don't know how to pass those values to the thread when using Queueing.

Comment: The threads are being created and added to the pool before any of the relevant data to be put into the threads is even generated. Is that okay? Can I pass the data into those threads afterwards somehow using Queue to put that data into a thread thats already into the thread pool?

Comment: You could do that with a Queue, but you don't really need a queue for that.

If passing in the value at thread creation time isn't sufficient, you should use option 2.